# Can Class Function get called by Threads and get access to class data?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

For a project that I have to make for school, I have been asked to make a program using threads. The library I am using is `<pthread.h>`. To understand how threads work I tried by writing some code in a blank file to see how they would behave. I actually discovered thank to another stackoverflow question how to pass to `pthread_create()` a class function, and it actually worked, but now have another problem and I couldn't find the answer anywhere. The program compiles and prints random integers that do not corrispond to the ones I have put inside the class. Maybe the methods getting called by threads can't access data inside of the class? That's the code:

```
class myClass {

    public:
        myClass() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                values[i] = i*3;
        }
        void myFunction() {
            
            pthread_t processIDs[5];
            int count[5];
            
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                count[i] = i;
                pthread_create(&processIDs[i], NULL, &printIntegerHelper, &count[i]);
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                pthread_join(processIDs[i], NULL);
            }
        }
    private:
        void* printInteger(int index) {
            printf("%d", values[index]);
        }
        static void* printIntegerHelper(void* arg) {
            Sleep(20);
            return ((myClass *) arg)->printInteger(*((int*)arg));
        }
    protected:
        int values[5];
};
int main(void){
    
    myClass myObject;
    
    myObject.myFunction();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(myClass*)arg`, `(int*)arg` - what do you expect by casting **the same** `arg` to two different types?

Comment: You can pass only one pointer. If you want to pass more, wrap that into a `struct` and pass a pointer to it.

Comment: Where did I pass more than a pointer? I'm just passing an index

Comment: Unrelated: What library provides the `<thread.h>` header? I do know the C functions in `<pthread.h>` - but why not use the C++ standard `<thread>` instead?

Comment: You didn't, and that's your problem. `arg` is a pointer to what? An object or an integer?

Comment: It's for a project I have to make for school. I honestly don't know why he chose this library instead of `<thread>`

Comment: The problem is that you cast `arg` pointer to two different types and then dereference it. One if these dereferences is undefined behaviour. If you want to pass more than one pointer (pointer + index), wrap it into a `struct` and pass a pointer to that struct.

Comment: You have a few other problems as well. `void* myFunction(void)` doesn't return a value but you've declared that it should return a `void*` - so your program has undefined behavior. Make it `void myFunction()` instead (skip `void` in the argument list - it has no impact in C++).

Comment: The function you call with `pthread_create()` must indeed be declared to return `void*` - but not the other functions that don't return anything.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I tried to write `void` instead of `void*` in `printInteger()` function and it gives me compilation error.

Comment: @ShaZeOfShiNy Ok, but not because of that change. It should give you less compiler warnings than if you declare it `void*` and does not return a `void*`.

Comment: I swear it doesn't. The program in the link doesn't do the same thing as your program. Your member function `myFunction` doesn't return anything and should be declared `void` - not `void*`. Your `printInteger` function on the other hand is expected to return a `void*` (since you return the return value in `printIntegerHelper`) but you don't return anything from it. Perhaps start by returning `nullptr` at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that you're trying to cast a single pointer `arg` to two pointers to different unrelated things and then dereference the result. You can't do it without  having an undefined behaviour. You can only pass one pointer to `pthread_create()`, and if you need to pass more than that (e.g., pointer + index), you need an additional indirection: wrap your information into a `struct` (or `std::pair`/`std::tuple`), then pass a pointer to it. That's what `std::thread` does internally.

Simple example:

```
using Data = std::pair<myClass*, int>;

void myFunction() {            
    // ...

    Data data[5];            
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        data[i] = {this, i};
        pthread_create(&processIDs[i], NULL, &printIntegerHelper, &data[i]);
    }

    // ... (all created threads are joined here, so
    //      accessing data inside a thread is safe)
}

static void* printIntegerHelper(void* arg) {
    const auto data = *reinterpret_cast<Data*>(arg);
    data.first->printInteger(data.second);
    return nullptr;
}
```

Also note that non-`void` functions should `return` something, even if that value isn't used later. The only exception is `int main(...)`.

Comment: Thank you!i It fixed my issue.

Comment: @Evg Fair point. I totally disregarded the joining of the threads in the same function since it's pretty uncommon :-) Removing comments and giving you my vote instead :-)